# Maximum Weight Sustained by wire / Breaking limit of wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, stress-strain, weight

I know that breaking stress depends on material of wire, not on the diameter or the length of wire. and also that Breaking load depends on the area of cross section of wire. But still i have a confusion in this question.

> a steel wire can sustain at the most 100 kg weight without breaking.if the wire is cut into equal parts , each parts can sustain at the most a weight of a) 400 kg b)100 kg c) 50 kg d) 200kg

Here the area of cross section remains the same so the breaking load also remains the same. And The lenght is halved but breaking stress does not depend on lenght of wire so it also remains the same. Does it mean that Both the halved wires can still sustain 100kg? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If you want to ask question here, please take a minute and read what we understand as homework: http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info. It doesn't have to be real homework.

Comment: Yes, each half of the wire can sustain at the most 100kg. Your analysis is correct (unless of course the wire has been cut in half longitudinally :-).

Comment: Isn't this a repost of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99738/maximum-weight-sustained-by-wire-breaking-limit-of-wire and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99973/max-weight-sustained-by-wire-or-breaking-limit-of-wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: both halves of the wire will still support the same weight. Look at it this way: the tension in each bit of the wire is the same regardless of whether the weight is hanging directly from it or suspended by another bit of wire in the middle. To put it in terms of stress, the force remains the same and the area remains the same, so the applied stress is also constant.